# Passing data id from a php loop to jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using PHP `foreach` loop to use create rating inputs:

```
<input id="input<?php echo $i ?>" data-id="<?php echo $i ?>" class="rating-loading">
```

The problem is `id="input"` should be unique for the jQuery function and I do not know how to pass this data id to the jQuery, I tried to make it something like this:

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
    $('#input'+id).rating({
        //my function
    });
});
```

However it is not working. If on top I make `id="input1"` and in the script I add `var id = 1;` it is working only for my first inputs inside loop, but I'm not sure how to pass this `data-id` to the jQuery. I even tried:

```
$(document).on('ready', function(){
    $(this).attr('data-id').rating({
        //my function
    });
});
```

However this is also not working. Please help me.

Comment: use common selector like class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use incremental `id` attributes; they quickly become a pain to maintain. Use a common class instead. Your inputs already have a `.rating-loading` class, so we can use that:

```
<input data-id="<?php echo $i ?>" class="rating-loading">
```

```js
$('.rating-loading').rating({
    //my function
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working. it was near 15 hours I was keep trying different ways, even I added another loops for the script to make it work but it did not.

Answer (score -1):

some thing below must work

```
      dataString = 'inID=' + valID
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
             url: "yourfile.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: 
                function(data) 
                    {
                        if (data='Posted')
                        {
                         ///
                        }//posted
                    }//function data
               });//ajax
```

Comment: Elaborate or clarify what the OP did wrong and what you improved/did differently. Just posting the code won't help OP understand the problem.

Comment: How is this even close to related to the OPs problem?